# Batch file says path missing, same command in cmd works

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm creating a batch file in Outlook VBA to resize images downloaded from the email.
The VBA code gives me a file like this:

```
call C:\src\scale.bat -source C:\src\details20.jpg -target "H:\Dokument\Avvikelser\2022\01\23\PENTA FOOD S.P.A\FÄNKÅL\60341\details20.jpg" -max-height 1000 -max-width 1000 -keep-ratio yes -force yes
call C:\src\scale.bat -source C:\src\details19.jpg -target "H:\Dokument\Avvikelser\2022\01\23\PENTA FOOD S.P.A\FÄNKÅL\60341\details19.jpg" -max-height 1000 -max-width 1000 -keep-ratio yes -force yes
call C:\src\scale.bat -source C:\src\details18.jpg -target "H:\Dokument\Avvikelser\2022\01\23\PENTA FOOD S.P.A\FÄNKÅL\60341\details18.jpg" -max-height 1000 -max-width 1000 -keep-ratio yes -force yes
call C:\src\scale.bat -source C:\src\details17.jpg -target "H:\Dokument\Avvikelser\2022\01\23\PENTA FOOD S.P.A\FÄNKÅL\60341\details17.jpg" -max-height 1000 -max-width 1000 -keep-ratio yes -force yes
call C:\src\scale.bat -source C:\src\details16.jpg -target "H:\Dokument\Avvikelser\2022\01\23\PENTA FOOD S.P.A\FÄNKÅL\60341\details16.jpg" -max-height 1000 -max-width 1000 -keep-ratio yes -force yes
call C:\src\scale.bat -source C:\src\details15.jpg -target "H:\Dokument\Avvikelser\2022\01\23\PENTA FOOD S.P.A\FÄNKÅL\60341\details15.jpg" -max-height 1000 -max-width 1000 -keep-ratio yes -force yes
call C:\src\scale.bat -source C:\src\details14.jpg -target "H:\Dokument\Avvikelser\2022\01\23\PENTA FOOD S.P.A\FÄNKÅL\60341\details14.jpg" -max-height 1000 -max-width 1000 -keep-ratio yes -force yes
call C:\src\scale.bat -source C:\src\details13.jpg -target "H:\Dokument\Avvikelser\2022\01\23\PENTA FOOD S.P.A\FÄNKÅL\60341\details13.jpg" -max-height 1000 -max-width 1000 -keep-ratio yes -force yes
call C:\src\scale.bat -source C:\src\details12.jpg -target "H:\Dokument\Avvikelser\2022\01\23\PENTA FOOD S.P.A\FÄNKÅL\60341\details12.jpg" -max-height 1000 -max-width 1000 -keep-ratio yes -force yes
call C:\src\scale.bat -source C:\src\details11.jpg -target "H:\Dokument\Avvikelser\2022\01\23\PENTA FOOD S.P.A\FÄNKÅL\60341\details11.jpg" -max-height 1000 -max-width 1000 -keep-ratio yes -force yes
call C:\src\scale.bat -source C:\src\details10.jpg -target "H:\Dokument\Avvikelser\2022\01\23\PENTA FOOD S.P.A\FÄNKÅL\60341\details10.jpg" -max-height 1000 -max-width 1000 -keep-ratio yes -force yes
call C:\src\scale.bat -source C:\src\details9.jpg -target "H:\Dokument\Avvikelser\2022\01\23\PENTA FOOD S.P.A\FÄNKÅL\60341\details9.jpg" -max-height 1000 -max-width 1000 -keep-ratio yes -force yes
call C:\src\scale.bat -source C:\src\details8.jpg -target "H:\Dokument\Avvikelser\2022\01\23\PENTA FOOD S.P.A\FÄNKÅL\60341\details8.jpg" -max-height 1000 -max-width 1000 -keep-ratio yes -force yes
call C:\src\scale.bat -source C:\src\details7.jpg -target "H:\Dokument\Avvikelser\2022\01\23\PENTA FOOD S.P.A\FÄNKÅL\60341\details7.jpg" -max-height 1000 -max-width 1000 -keep-ratio yes -force yes
call C:\src\scale.bat -source C:\src\details6.jpg -target "H:\Dokument\Avvikelser\2022\01\23\PENTA FOOD S.P.A\FÄNKÅL\60341\details6.jpg" -max-height 1000 -max-width 1000 -keep-ratio yes -force yes
call C:\src\scale.bat -source C:\src\details5.jpg -target "H:\Dokument\Avvikelser\2022\01\23\PENTA FOOD S.P.A\FÄNKÅL\60341\details5.jpg" -max-height 1000 -max-width 1000 -keep-ratio yes -force yes
call C:\src\scale.bat -source C:\src\details4.jpg -target "H:\Dokument\Avvikelser\2022\01\23\PENTA FOOD S.P.A\FÄNKÅL\60341\details4.jpg" -max-height 1000 -max-width 1000 -keep-ratio yes -force yes
call C:\src\scale.bat -source C:\src\details3.jpg -target "H:\Dokument\Avvikelser\2022\01\23\PENTA FOOD S.P.A\FÄNKÅL\60341\details3.jpg" -max-height 1000 -max-width 1000 -keep-ratio yes -force yes
call C:\src\scale.bat -source C:\src\details2.jpg -target "H:\Dokument\Avvikelser\2022\01\23\PENTA FOOD S.P.A\FÄNKÅL\60341\details2.jpg" -max-height 1000 -max-width 1000 -keep-ratio yes -force yes
call C:\src\scale.bat -source C:\src\details1.jpg -target "H:\Dokument\Avvikelser\2022\01\23\PENTA FOOD S.P.A\FÄNKÅL\60341\details1.jpg" -max-height 1000 -max-width 1000 -keep-ratio yes -force yes
call C:\src\scale.bat -source C:\src\details0.jpg -target "H:\Dokument\Avvikelser\2022\01\23\PENTA FOOD S.P.A\FÄNKÅL\60341\details0.jpg" -max-height 1000 -max-width 1000 -keep-ratio yes -force yes
TIMEOUT /T 2
del C:\src\details20.jpg
del C:\src\details19.jpg
del C:\src\details18.jpg
del C:\src\details17.jpg
del C:\src\details16.jpg
del C:\src\details15.jpg
del C:\src\details14.jpg
del C:\src\details13.jpg
del C:\src\details12.jpg
del C:\src\details11.jpg
del C:\src\details10.jpg
del C:\src\details9.jpg
del C:\src\details8.jpg
del C:\src\details7.jpg
del C:\src\details6.jpg
del C:\src\details5.jpg
del C:\src\details4.jpg
del C:\src\details3.jpg
del C:\src\details2.jpg
del C:\src\details1.jpg
del C:\src\details0.jpg
```

The source and target is dynamic, the rest is static.

It has worked fine on all files and folders except this here. I believe it's because of the Ä and Å in target.
When the code runs I get the following: `C:\src\scale.bat(310, 1) WIA.ImageFile.1: Det går inte att hitta sökvägen.` (Can't find path)

If I copy the command from the batch file to my cmd window it works as it should:

[image]
(19 & 20 was done manually before this post)

What is the reason why the batch file does not work but the same code in cmd runs fine?

EDIT: I found posts about using `chcp 65001` but either I don't understand how to or it doesn't work.

Edit:

scale.bat

```
@if (@X)==(@Y) @end /* JScript comment 
        @echo off        
        cscript //E:JScript //nologo "%~f0" %* 
        ::pause
        exit /b %errorlevel%       
@if (@X)==(@Y) @end JScript comment */ 

//https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms630819(v=vs.85).aspx

var imageFile = new ActiveXObject("WIA.ImageFile"); 
var imageProcess = new ActiveXObject("WIA.ImageProcess");
var fileSystem = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
var ARGS=WScript.Arguments;

/******
Scale filter description:

Scales image to the specified Maximum Width and Maximum Height preserving
Aspect Ratio if necessary.


MaximumWidth        - Set the MaximumWidth property to the width (in pixels)
                      that you wish to scale the image to.
MaximumHeight       - Set the MaximumHeight property to the height (in pixels)
                      that you wish to scale the image to.
PreserveAspectRatio - Set the PreserveAspectRatio property to True
                      [the default] if you wish to maintain the current aspect
                      ration of the image, otherwise False and the image will
                      be stretched to the MaximumWidth and MaximumHeight
FrameIndex          - Set the FrameIndex property to the index of a frame if
                      you wish to modify a frame other than the ActiveFrame,
                      otherwise 0 [the default]
                      

******/

//defaults

var maxWidth=0;
var maxHeight=0;

var pRatio=true;
var frameIndex=0;

var source="";
var target="";

var force=false;

var height=0;
var width=0;

var percentage=false;

////////////////////////////
////                      //
/**/     var QUALITY=100; //
////                      //
////////////////////////////

function existsFile(path){
    if (fileSystem.FileExists(path))
        return true;
}

function existsFolder(path){
    if (fileSystem.FolderExists(path))
        return true;
}

function deleteFile(path){
    fileSystem.DeleteFile(path);
}

function loadImage(image,imageFile){
    try{
       image.LoadFile(imageFile);
    }catch(err){
       WScript.Echo("Probably "+imageFile+" is not a valid image file");
       WScript.Echo(err.message);
       WScript.Quit(30);
    }
    height=image.Height;
    width=image.Width;
}

function ID2Format(id){
    var ids={};
    ids["{B96B3CAB-0728-11D3-9D7B-0000F81EF32E}"]="BPM";
    ids["{B96B3CAF-0728-11D3-9D7B-0000F81EF32E}"]="PNG";
    ids["{B96B3CB0-0728-11D3-9D7B-0000F81EF32E}"]="GIF";
    ids["{B96B3CAE-0728-11D3-9D7B-0000F81EF32E}"]="JPG";
    ids["{B96B3CB1-0728-11D3-9D7B-0000F81EF32E}"]="TIFF";
    
    return ids[id];
}

function format2ID(format){
    formats={};
    formats["BMP"]="{B96B3CAB-0728-11D3-9D7B-0000F81EF32E}";
    formats["PNG"]="{B96B3CAF-0728-11D3-9D7B-0000F81EF32E}";
    formats["GIF"]="{B96B3CB0-0728-11D3-9D7B-0000F81EF32E}";
    formats["JPG"]="{B96B3CAE-0728-11D3-9D7B-0000F81EF32E}";
    formats["TIFF"]="{B96B3CB1-0728-11D3-9D7B-0000F81EF32E}";
    
    return formats[format];
}

function convert(image,format){
    var ic=imageProcess.Filters.Count;
    var filterFormat=format2ID(format);
    if(filterFormat==null){
        WScript.Echo("not supported target format "+format);
        WScript.Quit(90);
    }
    imageProcess.Filters.Add(imageProcess.FilterInfos("Convert").FilterID);
    imageProcess.Filters(ic+1).Properties("FormatID").Value = filterFormat;
    imageProcess.Filters(ic+1).Properties("Quality").Value = QUALITY;
}

function scale(){
    if(maxHeight<=0){
        WScript.Echo("MaximumHeight ("+maxHeight+") should be bigger than 0");
        WScript.Quit(80);
    }
    
    if(maxWidth<=0){
        WScript.Echo("MaximumHeight ("+maxWidth+") should be bigger than 0");
        WScript.Quit(81);
    }
    
    var ic=imageProcess.Filters.Count;
    //var filterFormat=format2ID(format);
    imageProcess.Filters.Add(imageProcess.FilterInfos("Scale").FilterID);
    
    imageProcess.Filters(ic+1).Properties("MaximumWidth").Value = maxWidth;
    imageProcess.Filters(ic+1).Properties("MaximumHeight").Value = maxHeight;
    //WScript.Echo(pRatio+"::"+maxWidth+"::"+maxHeight+">>"+width+"++"+height);
    imageProcess.Filters(ic+1).Properties("PreserveAspectRatio").Value = pRatio;
    imageProcess.Filters(ic+1).Properties("FrameIndex").Value = frameIndex;
}

function fromPerc(){
    maxWidth=Math.round((width*maxWidth)/100);
    maxHeight=Math.round((height*maxHeight)/100);
    if(maxHeight==0)
        maxHeight=1;
    if(maxWidth==0)
        maxWidth=1;
}


function printHelp(){

    WScript.Echo( WScript.ScriptName + " - resizes an image");
    WScript.Echo(" ");
    WScript.Echo(WScript.ScriptName + "-source source.file -target file.format [-max-height height] [-max-width width] [-percentage yes|no] [-keep-ratio yes|no] [-frame-index -0.5..1] ");
    WScript.Echo("-source  - the image that will flipped or rotated.");
    WScript.Echo("-target  - the file where the transformations will be saved in.If the file extension format is different than the source it will be converted to the pointed one.Supported formats are BMp,JPG,GIF,TIFF,PNG");
    WScript.Echo("-percentage  - whether the rescale will be calculated in pixels or in percentages.If yes percentages will be used.Default is no.");
    WScript.Echo("-force  - If yes and the target file already exists , it will be overwritten");
    WScript.Echo("-max-height - max height of the image");
    WScript.Echo("-max-width - max width of the image");
    WScript.Echo("-keep-ratio - if dimensions ratio will be preserved.Default is yes");
    WScript.Echo("-frame-index - Have no idea what this is used for , but it is pressented in the rotation filter capabilities.Images with this and without looks the same.Accepted values are from -0.5 to 1");
    
}

function parseArguments(){
    if (WScript.Arguments.Length<4 || ARGS.Item(1).toLowerCase() == "-help" ||  ARGS.Item(1).toLowerCase() == "-h" ) {
        printHelp();
        WScript.Quit(0);
   }
   
    if (WScript.Arguments.Length % 2 == 1 ) {
        WScript.Echo("Illegal arguments ");
        printHelp();
        WScript.Quit(1);
    }
    
    //ARGS
    for(var arg = 0 ; arg<ARGS.Length-1;arg=arg+2) {
        if (ARGS.Item(arg) == "-source") {
            source = ARGS.Item(arg +1);
        }
        if (ARGS.Item(arg) == "-target") {
            target = ARGS.Item(arg +1);
        }

        if (ARGS.Item(arg).toLowerCase() == "-force" && (ARGS.Item(arg +1).toLowerCase() == "yes" || ARGS.Item(arg +1).toLowerCase() == "true") ) {
            force=true;
        }
        
        if (ARGS.Item(arg).toLowerCase() == "-percentage" && (ARGS.Item(arg +1).toLowerCase() == "yes" || ARGS.Item(arg +1).toLowerCase() == "true") ) {
            percentage=true;
        }
        
        if (ARGS.Item(arg).toLowerCase() == "-keep-ratio" && (ARGS.Item(arg +1).toLowerCase() == "no" || ARGS.Item(arg +1).toLowerCase() == "false") ) {
            pRatio=false;
        }
        
        if (ARGS.Item(arg).toLowerCase() == "-max-width") {
            try {
                maxWidth=parseInt(ARGS.Item(arg +1));               
            } catch (err){
                WScript.Echo("Wrong argument:");
                WScript.Echo(err.message);
                WScript.Quit(10);
            }
            
        }
        
        if (ARGS.Item(arg).toLowerCase() == "-max-height") {
            try {
                maxHeight=parseInt(ARGS.Item(arg +1));              
            } catch (err){
                WScript.Echo("Wrong argument:");
                WScript.Echo(err.message);
                WScript.Quit(15);
            }
            
        }
        
        
        if (ARGS.Item(arg).toLowerCase() == "-frame-index") {
            try {
                frameIndex=parseFloat(ARGS.Item(arg +1));
                if(frameIndex<-0.5 || frameIndex > 1){
                    WScript.Echo("Wrong argument - frame index should be between -0.5 and 1");
                    WScript.Quit(25);
                }
                
            } catch (err){
                WScript.Echo("Wrong argument:");
                WScript.Echo(err.message);
                WScript.Quit(20);
            }           
        }       
    }
    
    if (target==""){
        WScript.Echo("Target file not passed");
        WScript.Quit(5);
    }
    
    if(source==""){
        WScript.Echo("Source file not passed");
        WScript.Quit(6);
    }
}

parseArguments();

if(!existsFile(source)){
    WScript.Echo("Source image: " + source +" does not exists");
    WScript.Quit(40);
}

if(existsFile(target) && !force){
    WScript.Echo("Target image: " + target +" already exists");
    WScript.Quit(45);
}

if(existsFolder(target)){
    WScript.Echo("There's existing folder with the target file  (" + target +") name");
    WScript.Quit(46);
}

if(existsFile(target) && force){
    deleteFile(target);
}

var targetFormat=target.split(".")[target.split(".").length-1].toUpperCase();
loadImage(imageFile,source);
var sourceFormat=ID2Format(imageFile.FormatID);


if(maxWidth==0 && !percentage){
    maxWidth=width;
}

if(maxHeight==0 && !percentage){
    maxHeight=height;
}

if(maxWidth==0 && percentage){
    maxWidth=100;
}

if(maxHeight==0 && percentage){
    maxHeight=100;
}


if(percentage){
    fromPerc();
}



///
scale();
///

if (sourceFormat !== targetFormat ){
    convert(resImg,targetFormat);
}

var resImg=imageProcess.Apply(imageFile);
resImg.SaveFile(target);
```

(part of) VBA code:

```
        MyFile = "C:\src\cmdcode.bat"
        fnum = FreeFile()
        Open MyFile For Output As #fnum
        fcall = ""
        fdel = ""
        
        For i = d.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
            If Left(d.Keys()(i), 4) <> "bild" And Find = True Then Exit For
            If Left(d.Keys()(i), 4) = "bild" Then
                Find = True

                dest = sSaveFolderjpg & "\" & Right(d(d.Keys()(i)), Len(d(d.Keys()(i))) - InStrRev(d(d.Keys()(i)), "/"))
                If Dir(dest) <> "" Then
                
                Else
                    ret = DownloadFile(d.Items(i), "C:\src\" & Mid(d.Items(i), InStrRev(d.Items(i), "/") + 1, 15))
                    
                    fcall = fcall & vbNewLine & "call C:\src\scale.bat -source C:\src\" & Mid(d.Items(i), InStrRev(d.Items(i), "/") + 1, 15) & " -target " & Chr(34) & dest & Chr(34) & " -max-height 1000 -max-width 1000 -keep-ratio yes -force yes"
                    fdel = fdel & vbNewLine & "del C:\src\" & Mid(d.Items(i), InStrRev(d.Items(i), "/") + 1, 15)


                End If
            End If
        Next i
        Print #fnum, fcall
        Print #fnum, "TIMEOUT /T 2"
        Print #fnum, fdel
        
        Close #fnum
        
        wsh.Run MyFile, windowStyle, waitOnReturn
```

The loop loops through the elements of the email and if it finds images it saves it in a temporary folder and generates a batch file to resize the images.

Comment: My best guess is, that the special characters `Ä` and `Ã` get lost when the batch file is written, which is (or should be) ASCII/ANSI encoding. Why are you using a batch file for this after all? Anyway, would you mind sharing `scale.bat` as well as your VBA code?

Comment: I wouldn't say they are lost since they are there in the file. What you see in the question is copy pasted from the batch file. The command in the cmd window is also copied from the batch file. As far as I know VBA does not have resize capabilities.

Comment: Apparently there is a good way to resize in VBA... https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/shrink-pictures-in-a-folder.1158445/post-5622237

Comment: I's say that your current directory is different. could you devise to execute a `pushd "C:\src"` before your `call` sequence and a `popd` after? (Quick-and-dirty solution - I've no intention of reading War-and-Peace... :))